# How to move navbar items at the right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm using bootstrap classes and I need the logo to be in the left but nav items at the right.
To be responsive as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvLvo.jpg
[navbar now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8eju.jpg)

```
       <!-- Logo -->
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
           <img class="img-fluid" src="images/header-logo.png" alt="logo">
       </a>

       <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <!-- Nav items -->
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar"> <!-- Collapse navbar -->
           <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </nav>
```

Comment: at the top I have
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">

Comment: Please edit this in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `ml-auto` to your `ul` class, which gives your `ul` a `margin-left` of `auto`. It will look like this:

`<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`

Comment: So mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use float right to move nav bar right side

```
#collapsibleNavbar{
 float: right;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// CSS code
nav #collapsibleNavbar{
    width: n%; // n = o que achar melhor
    margin: n n;
    display: block;
}
nav #collapsibleNavbar .navbar-nav{
    display: block;
    width: auto; // or what You think is better for your project
    margin: n n;
    float: right;
}
```

I think you can try that and to encapsulate in a div your Logo and Toggler/collapsibe Button, setting div to float left. Maybe you'll need add some "!important".